# Which cloud service to be used for enabling Push notification services (WNS) -WINDOWS PHONE 8.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst, azure-cloud-services, wns

Developed hybrid application using **IBM mobile First studio** as per windows phone application 8 is concerned I have upgraded this to **Windows phone 8.1** using Visual Studio 2013.

In order to add push notification concept(WNS) to my application.
Followed the following steps

1. Imported project to **VS 2013** --> Re targeted to **8.1**
2. Opened **Package.appmanifest.xml** --> Application Tab --> Toast
   Capable-->Enabled(yes)
3. Lock screen notifications --> **Enabled**(Yes)
4. Opened **WMAppManifest.xml**
   --> **ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION** --> **Enabled**
5. Selected **WNS** as the notification service in app’s **Package.appxmanifest
   file.**
6. [This is the architecture I am following.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187203.aspx)

Where else should I modify my Java coding to make it **Push Enabled application.**

Also what kind of **cloud service** should I use in here? Currently I have researched about [AZURE mobile services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-phone-get-started-push/) will this be the only one, since it is recommended by Microsoft in my DEVELOPER DASH BOARD.

Comment: WNS is applicable only to Windows 8. 
If you are working on Windows Phone (Silverlight) , then you need to use MPNS notifications.
While adding environments, which one did you choose?

Comment: Hi @VivinK I have chosen Windows phone 8 Environment and FYI  [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642085%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) clearly shows that we can use WNS for Windows phone (Silver Light), I have also seen a Video by Microsoft where they clearly projected that in future windows(Desktop & Mobile) stays on WNS.

Comment: My response was with respect to what MobileFirst supports. In MobileFirst, WNS is supported only on Windows 8 and not Silverlight. Only MPNS works for Silverlight projects , in MobileFirst.
The future shift to WNS is with UWP. There will be no Silverlight then.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarifying on that @VivinK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Vivin, in MobileFirst you cannot use WNS for the Windows Phone 8 environment.

First change your configuration to use MPNS as the MobileFirst user documentation dictates and open a new question if you have any additional issues after changing the configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Vivin & Idan Adar for that response.